# Docker Cannot start service cadvisor: oci runtime error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### The error

```sh
$ docker-compose ps
        Name                      Command                State                      Ports                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cadvisor               /usr/bin/cadvisor -logtost ...   Exit 128                                           
dozzle                 /dozzle                          Up         8080/tcp                                
grafana                /run.sh                          Up         3000/tcp                                
node_exporter          /bin/node_exporter --path. ...   Up                                                 
prometheus             /bin/prometheus --config.f ...   Up         9090/tcp
```

```sh
ERROR: for cadvisor  Cannot start service cadvisor: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "container init exited prematurely"
```

### Context

```sh
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux mydomain.net 3.10.0-1160.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 20 16:53:08 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 0be3e21/1.13.1

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.26.0, build d4451659
```

### In my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:latest
    container_name: cadvisor
    privileged: true
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/cgroup:ro
      - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct:/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct,cpu:rw
    #command: ["--logtostderr=true", "--raw_cgroup_prefix_whitelist=/docker/", "--v=4"]
    command: ["--logtostderr=true", "--docker_only=true", "--v=1"]
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8080
    networks:
      - internal
```

My problem started happening overnight, it used to work ... may be a software update. Any pointers?

Comment: If you need a privileged container that's mounting every system-related filesystem into the container, you may find it much easier to run the process directly on the host, as root, not in a container.  Is there any of your own application source code that's important to the question, or are you just trying to run this prebuilt image?

Comment: Did you consider updating docker? Version you are using is pretty outdated 1.13.1 (2017-02-08)